# Append name of parent folders and subfolders to the names of the multiple files

Tags: unix, shell, system-administration

I have folders and subfolders with 10K photos in them.

Now I need to put all 10K files into one folder. I want to append the folder and subfolder name with the existing file name so that the file name becomes meaningful to me.

I need help

Answer (score 8):

You can write a quick shell script to do this for you.  To get the name of the current folder:

```
pwd|awk -F'/' '{print $NF}'
```

and to get the current folder's parent:

```
pwd|awk -F'/' '{SL = NF-1; print $SL}'
```

**Update**

Create a file that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in `find . -name '*jpg'`
do
   filename=`echo $f|awk -F'/' '{SL = NF-1; TL = NF-2; print $TL "_" $SL  "_" $NF}'`
   cp $f newfolder/$filename
done
```

and then do `chmod +x` on it.  Run the script in the top level.  In this case, you need to make the destination, newfolder, ahead of time.

I took this directory structure:

```
./bar
./bar/baz
./bar/baz/1.jpg
./bar/baz/2.jpg
./bar/baz/3.jpg
./bar/buz
./bar/buz/1.jpg
./bar/buz/2.jpg
./bar/buz/3.jpg
./foo
./foo/baz
./foo/baz/1.jpg
./foo/baz/2.jpg
./foo/baz/3.jpg
./foo/buz
./foo/buz/1.jpg
./foo/buz/2.jpg
./foo/buz/3.jpg
```

And made it into this:

```
./newfolder/bar_baz_1.jpg
./newfolder/bar_baz_2.jpg
./newfolder/bar_baz_3.jpg
./newfolder/bar_buz_1.jpg
./newfolder/bar_buz_2.jpg
./newfolder/bar_buz_3.jpg
./newfolder/foo_baz_1.jpg
./newfolder/foo_baz_2.jpg
./newfolder/foo_baz_3.jpg
./newfolder/foo_buz_1.jpg
./newfolder/foo_buz_2.jpg
./newfolder/foo_buz_3.jpg
```

Hope that is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much for prompt help. Would you elaborate a bit more. should I create batch file for this? or how to execute it?

Comment: I updated the answer to include a shell script.